# Setting empty (blank) cookies in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, cookies

I am using cookies to store some data on client side.

The data i am storing in cookies is coming from database which can be null. I am checking whether it is null or not and based on that i am assigning value to variable.

```
if(rs.getString("publicationDateFrom") == null || rs.getString("publicationDateFrom").equals(""))
 str[8] = "";
else
 str[8] = rs.getString("publicationDateFrom").trim();
```

**IN JSP**

```
publicationDateFrom = new Cookie("publicationDateFrom",str[8]);
publicationDateFrom.setMaxAge(60*60*24*exTime); 
publicationDateFrom.setPath("/");
response.addCookie( publicationDateFrom );
```

In case when `str[8]` is empty, why my cookie is showing value of `""`. its string length is 2

Comment: Because, you are checking for your request variable not be null or empty. But, your cookie is getting created even its empty. That's why an empty cookie named "publicationDateFrom" is created.

Comment: If you print out the str[8] in the JSP, what value gets printed?

Comment: when i using log it show nothing, string length was 0

Comment: @ParkashKumar I want to create empty cookie, but its not empty it contains two doublequotes in it

Comment: using log length of string `""` is 0(zero).

Comment: @shadow : Double quotes are contained because your value at array index 8 is double-quote / "".

Comment: @aniket It actually containg value as two double quotes ("") string length 2

Comment: @ParkashKumar No its not when i used console.log it is empty, but when i am setting value of cookie, the cookie is having value of 2 double quotes

Comment: Check all legal values you can use, though you are not using this method http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#setValue(java.lang.String) but the value part must be legal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it browser dependent

According to these [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#setValue%28java.lang.String%29)

Empty values may not behave the same way on all browsers.

Comment: This is what I commented before this answer see comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20882817/setting-empty-blank-cookies-in-jsp#comment31338365_20882817)

Answer (score 0):

[Refer this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_cookies_handling.htm)

Setting Cookies with JSP:

```
Setting cookies with JSP involves three steps:

(1) Creating a Cookie object: You call the Cookie constructor with a cookie name and a cookie value, both of which are strings.

Cookie cookie = new Cookie("key","value");

Keep in mind, neither the name nor the value should contain white space or any of the following characters:

[ ] ( ) = , " / ? @ : ;

(2) Setting the maximum age: You use setMaxAge to specify how long (in seconds) the cookie should be valid. Following would set up a cookie for 24 hours.

cookie.setMaxAge(60*60*24); 

(3) Sending the Cookie into the HTTP response headers: You use response.addCookie to add cookies in the HTTP response header as follows:

response.addCookie(cookie);
```